# Is there a List that works like an Array?

Tags: java, arrays, list

Is there a type of `List`, that works like an array?
I want to be able to predefine the absolute size of the `List`, so everything that isn't defined in it, but its index lays in the size, should be `null` if I get a value. I also want to overwrite null-values if I use the `add()` method is something like that already implemented, or do I have to make my own?

I already tried `ArrayList`s, but if I get a value with the index I which is less than the capacity, but not less than the size, it throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: ArrayList will likely fit your bill. But I assume that you've Googled this and that this would be your first hit -- and so your coming here makes me wonder if you have reservations on using this, and if so why? Please clarify.

Comment: Sounds like an array would be the thing you would like.

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? Changing one thing to behave like another is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Hmm, `I want to be able to predefine the absolute size of the List`, if you don't want the size to change at all, what's wrong with a regular `array`?

Comment: Can you show an example of `IndexOutOfBoundsException` you're getting with an `ArrayList`?

Comment: You can't access an index larger than size() - 1; Capacity is different from size

Comment: " if I get a value with the index i which is less than the capacity, but not less than the size," I think you mean, "less than the size, but not less than the capacity".  `add()` doesn't make any sense if you have a fixed size, so I suspect you requirements need clarification.

Comment: to clarify, i kinda need a list that only has a length like arrays, so capacity = size

Comment: why not just make your own? You only need a set, get and size method. in your get you can define to return null if the index is outside the array size.

Comment: Seriously, why make something complex behave exactly as simple arrays when you can just use arrays?

Comment: Why not just use normal arrays and use the `[]` operator ?

Comment: zabri, arrays dont have .add :D

Comment: I haven't heard of a `List` implementation as crippled by design as you want it to be. I'm afraid you'll have to implement something of your own by breaking an `ArrayList`'s knees with a baseball bat and wrapping it inside your own class implementing the `List` interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you need a JavaScript-like array. What you could do is to derive from an `ArrayList`, overload the capacity constructor and return null if index is bigger than a size:

```
static class JSLikeArray<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
    public JSLikeArray(int initialCapacity) {
        super(initialCapacity);
    }

    @Override
    public E get(int index) {
        if (index >= size()) return null;

        return super.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public E set(int index, E element) {
        int l = index + 1;
        for (int i = size(); i < l; i++) {
            add(null);
        }

        super.set(index, element);

        return element;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSLikeArray<Integer> array = new JSLikeArray<Integer>(10);

    array.set(3, 3);

    System.out.println("array before add: " + array);
    System.out.println("array.get(10): " + array.get(10));
    array.add(4);
    System.out.println("array after add: " + array);
}
```

Prints:

```
array before add: [null, null, null, 3]
array.get(10): null
array after add:  [null, null, null, 3, 4]
```

Comment: that's pretty much what i wanted, except the add method, i modified it a bit, so it also overrides nulls :D ty :P

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, there are some uses of this structure that require it to be a List rather than an array.

The structure that does best at acting like an array is an array. Use that, but in contexts that require a List view of the structure, use Arrays.asList.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do need your own implementation due to this particular requirements of yours: `get` works beyond current size and returns `null`. Neither plain arrays nor any `List` implementation has such semantics.

You need something very similar to an `ArrayList` so it may pay to extend from it, overriding `get` to change the behavior for indexes between `size` and `capacity`.

You may also choose to start from `AbstractList`, which will help you by implementing all the `List` interface methods which can be defined in terms of a core subset of essential operations.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
List<MyObject> list = Arrays.asList(new MyObject[SIZE]);
```

This will create a List backed by the array of the specified size, pre-filled with nulls. This list is mutable but is of fixed size. You can use `set` to change values at particular locations, but `add` and `remove` will throw exceptions. Plus the rest of the `List` and `Collection` APIs will work for reading and iterating, which is probably your intent.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    a.add(i, null);
}
a.add(5, "string");
```

This will create an `ArrayList` of the size 20 filled with `null`s. The method `add(int index, String element)` really updates the `null` on the given index with the given element.

However, you can't use the simple `add(String)` method anymore, since that would just add a 21st (and so on) element. I don't think there is a way you can tell a `List` not to accept values anymore. That's pretty much why they were created, so that you can add values to it all over without having to care about their size...

You can, however, extend the `ArrayList` class, set its size and prefill it with `null`s in its constructor and override the `add(String)` method to do nothing or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

> *"I already tried ArrayLists, but if I get a value with the index i which is less than the capacity, but not less than the size, it throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException.."*

size and capacity are two totally different thing. size is the actual number of elements in the list, while capacity if the memory capacity available, until it has to resize under the hood

So if you have capacity 10 and size 4, the greatest index you can access is 3.

When you first initialize the list, the size is 0. Everytime you add, the size increases by one, not the capacity.

Remember an arraylist is an array under the hood. The capacity is the array size i.e. `new int[10];`. But even though the array is sized at ten, the actual list isn't.  10 is the capacity of the list though. When the capacity is reached, the array will increase in size, increasing the capacity of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a class of your own say `class Array` and put all functionality init which you want. In your case it will be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you add an index outside of the bounds you are not working with a list. That is a requirement fitting an array.

In the end what I got from reading you want a List behave like a array. In order to do this you have to touch the ArrayList implementation. Subclass it and override every method that calles ensure capacity in order grow the list if adding the new element would exceed the current capacity of the list.

Just override the ensureCapacity and disable it throwing UnsupportedOperationException. Then you need to also disable remove operations by overwritting and throwing unsupported operation exception.

You might even want to override... . So you see lots to do.

Another simple idea is using a HashMap. Store integer to objects. If integer is out of bounds you can simply throw the IndexOutOfBoundsException within the put operation. And on get you return null anyway when the given index is not in the map.

This is nice but I wouldn't go that way.

In the end just warp an array. Use Array.fill to fill it up with nulls since in the sepcs it might be random but every implementation I ever saw it was always nulled out otherwise the JVM might break since the random content might be interpreted for being a reference.

So lets create a new one. You might implement the Collection interface or even the List interface but in the end one might only want to use it within a for each loop (for element : list). Therefore all you need to do is implement the Iterable interface.

The new class should have set(int index, T object) and T get(int index) and also int size(). Thats all.

---

### Bottomline:

Nope the List is not what you are looking for. Create your own implementation wraping an array. Implement Iterable and maybe if you like Collection and you are good to go.